# Filter SQL Server data using relevant filterations

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering

I have created a table named `[Damaged Item]` which contains items that are damaged, and it looks like this:

```
|  Item   |  Style    |  Date    |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|  A1     |    A      | 12/04/20 |
|         |    B      | 03/12/19 |
```

I have another table which maintains `[Purchased Items]`.

[Purchased Items] will drop an item if it is fulfilling following conditions.

1. If the item contains inside the Damaged item table and Date of Damaged item date is greater than current date.
2. If the item field inside in Damaged Item is NULL or '' then I have to check the Style column. If the purchased items' style is equal to damaged style then I'm dropping those values as well if the Date of Damaged item date is greater than current date.

Please note that if there is a Item in Damaged Item table then Purchased items will be checked with Damaged items and check the date and if the Damaged item date is greater than current date I'm dropping that item else If there is no Item but only Style then I'm checking Style with Purchased Items' Style and check the date condition and dropping the records. If Damaged Item contains data like above then I'm checking Item as well as Style.

I put a LEFT Join like this.

```
[PurchasedItem] X 
LEFT JOIN [DamagedItem] D ON (X.ITNO = D.ITNO)
LEFT JOIN [DamagedItem] E ON (X.Style = E.Style)
```

This query (`X.ITNO = D.ITNO`) is dropping items but from second join it is getting that dropped items again (as `D.ITNO AS NULL`).

Can somebody help me to do this?

Comment: Why is the first column `NULL` in the second row?

Comment: Sample data, from _both_ tables, current results, and desired results would help a lot to clarify this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if the Item is NULL we have to check with Style field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out damaged items, you can use `not exists`:

```
selet pi.*
from PurchasedItem pi
where not exists (select 1
                  from DamagedItem di
                  where di.ITNO = pi.ITNO and di.date > getdate()
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from DamagedItem di
                  where di.ITNO is null and
                        di.style = pi.style and
                        di.date > getdate()
                 );
```

The date arithemtic looks strange (future damage?), but that is what you are asking for.